# Tab control + DataGridView in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have multiple results sets coming back from a server request against a datasource.  I want to organise these with a WinForms tabPage for each result set, on a single tabControl.  I am displaying the data in a DataGridView, but want to avoid having a DataGridView instance on each tabPage - I'd rather intercept the "switching to new tab page" message, and load up the appropriate results set from my local cache.  Is there an easy/obvious way to do this?

Comment: any final solution with full source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a tab control as usual and then put a DataGridView on top of it (be sure not to put it inside a tab page).

Subscribe to the SelectedIndexChanged event and reload the data when the event fires.

Comment: Yup, literally 30 seconds ago figured that approach for myself - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this? You'd lose the designability per result set (unless they're all the same structure) and have to manage all of this yourself.

Comment: They are all the same structure, it's multiple results for different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub AddDGVInTab(Form As Control, DGV As DataGridView)
    Form.Controls.Add(DGV)
    DGV.BringToFront()
End Sub
```

Use this procedure on Click, Texchange Events